# Error in UseMethod("select_") in Blogdown

Tags: r, tidyverse, blogdown

I am using `Blogdown` to create a new post and I am getting the following error when trying to preview.
The code works well in my Rmarkdown file but I cannot update it to my blog. Do anyone know where the problem is?

Quitting from lines 36-47
Error in UseMethod("select_") : 
  no applicable method for 'select_' applied to an object of class "function"
Calls: local ... freduce ->  -> select -> select.default -> select_
Execution halted

Here is my code in lines 36-47;

```
library(corrplot)
library(RColorBrewer)
library(tidyverse)
corrplot(cor(df %>% select(Sales, Customers, Store, 
                           Open, SchoolHoliday, 
                           DayOfWeek, month, year, 
                           CompetitionDistance,
                           Promo, Promo2_active) %>%
               filter(!is.na(Sales), !is.na(CompetitionDistance))), 
         type="upper", order="original",
         col=brewer.pal(n=8, name="RdYlBu"))
```

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're getting this error because you don't have an object called `df` in your global environment. Either your data frame hasn't been created yet or it is called something else. There is a little-known function called `df` in the stats package, which is on the search path when you start an R session. You can check this by starting a new R session and typing `df` into the console. You will see the body of the function `stats::df`.

You are therefore getting the error because you are trying to subset a function, not a data frame. To resolve the error, make sure you create a data frame called `df` before your call to `corrplot`

Comment: Thanks Allan. I have already created `df` and I confirmed its class as "data.frame" by calling `class(df)`. Actually everything works fine when I call `corrplot`. This error happens only when I render this Rmd file.

Comment: @JamesDiu but are you creating the df within your Rmd file or is it just an object in your R session? If it's the latter, that won't work

Comment: Yes, I have created `df` in another Rmd, which does not belong to this post. Everything is ok after I load `df` again in this post. Thanks a lot!